# Run function/void in a class extending InputMethodService

Tags: java, android, class

I have this MainClass which extends the InputMethodService (shortened version):

```
public class PcAsKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private Keyboard mKeyboard;

    private KeyboardView mInputView;

    private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        ServerThread chatServerThread = new ServerThread(this);     
        chatServerThread.start();        
    }

    public void output(CharSequence text) {
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(text, 1); // Sends CharSequence "text" to input field
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the function/void "output" from another class (shortened):

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {  

    // the socket where to listen/talk  
    Socket socket;

    InputStream inputStream;

    //InputMethodService ims = new InputMethodService();

    String message;

    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    //private PcAsKeyboard main = null;    


    // Constructor
    ClientThread(Socket socket, PcAsKeyboard main) {

        this.socket = socket;

        // Creating stream for data input & a reader for the stream to get the message
        try
        {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            // Exception creating InputStream!

            return;

        }

    }   


    // Runs forever
    public void run() {

        while(true) {   
            // Trying to get a line from the input stream   
            try {
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }   
            catch (IOException e) { 
                // "Exception reading InputStream!
                break;              
            }               
            // TODO: Write var message in input Field
            // main.output(message);            
            // ims.getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(message, 1); 
        }       

        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

At "// TODO: Write var message in input Field" I want to run the output function with the variable "message". 
I already tried to transfer the main class (PcAsKeyboard) as a variable when creating the "ClientThread" class but this didn't work/gave null pointer exception. This also happened when I tried to access the "InputMethodService" and calling ".getCurrentInputConnection()" then.

I hope someone of you can help me out with this ^-^

Comment: I suppose in the first piece of code you are creating `ClientThread` instead of `ServerThread`? What's the problem in adding `this.main = main;` in the `ClientThread` constructor?

Comment: @AntonSavin Oh, actually at first the ServerThread is created which later creates the ClientThread.
And it seems like I forgot this in the ClientThread construcor - silly me <.< Now it's working properly, thank you ^-^

Comment: And somewhere on the way you forget to pass the `main`.

Comment: Yea, see my edited comment